# decimal point in \si

Tags: siunitx

i am using the following command:

```
$\si{202.889*202.915*185.759}{\angstrom}$
```

the numbers are shown without decimal points, and \SI is not working for me.

my permeable file has the following packages:

```
    \documentclass[12pt,reqno]{report}
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb}
\newcommand{\angstrom}{\textup{\AA}}
\usepackage{empheq}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\DeclareSIUnit\angstrom{\mathrm{\AA}}
\setlength{\parindent}{1em}
\setlength{\parskip}{1em}
\renewcommand{\baselinestretch}{1.5}
\usepackage[style=numeric, sorting=none]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{library.bib}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes.geometric, arrows}
\usepackage{listings}
\usepackage{xcolor}
```

Comment: `202.889*202.915*185.759` isn't a valid number for `siunitx`: the first thing you should get is an error to that effect

Comment: ok, the question is how to format an invalid number for this particular case, i got to present 3 numbers in x y z plane...

Comment: Slight typo: it should be `$\SI{202.889*202.915*185.759}{\angstrom}$` (capital SI)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You seem to be looking for a product of dimensions, so something like

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\DeclareSIUnit\angstrom{\text {Å}}
\ifdefined\qtyproduct\else
  \NewCommandCopy\qtyproduct\SI
\fi
\begin{document}
$\qtyproduct{202.889 x 202.915 x 185.759}{\angstrom}$
\end{document}
```

(I've used the v3 interface and ensured that if v2 is loaded it will still work: the older name was just `\SI`, but that was not great semantically.)

Comment: \DeclareSIUnit\angstrom{\text {Å}}
threw that error:
LaTeX Error: Missing \begin{document}.

\begindocument is definitely included

Comment: @KhalidHelmy What error? I've tried with v2 and v3 and it's fine

Comment: i am trying to use "\qtyproduct command with the following text:

10 gridpoints/angstrom

how to convert "angstrom" to the unit symbol?

Comment: @KhalidHelmy I've no idea what you are getting at without an example - it doesn't sound like the same question

Comment: thank you, i figured it out with \qtyproduct command
appreciate your input